# Meteor subscribe undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

i new in meteor, I want to make a registration form use meteor, and i stuck in `findOne` and `subscribe/publish` . 
this is my `collection.js common :

```
User_Customer = new Meteor.Collection("USER_CUSTOMER");
Customer = new Meteor.Collection("CUSTOMER");
```

this is my `publish.js` `/server`:

```
Meteor.publish("CUSTOMER", function() {
    return Customer.find();
});

Meteor.publish("USER_CUSTOMER", function() {
    return User_Customer.find();
});
```

and this is my function to subscribe and findOne `/client` :

```
function isAvailableForUserRegister(email,identiy,phone){
    Meteor.subscribe("CUSTOMER", function(){
        var cust = null;
        cust = Customer.findOne({Identity: identiy});
        if(cust != null){
            Meteor.subscribe("USER_CUSTOMER", function(){
                var uc1 = null;
                uc1 = User_Customer.findOne({Email: email});
                if(uc1 != null){
                    var uc2 = null;
                    uc2 = User_Customer.findOne({Phone: phone});
                    if(uc2 != null)
                        return true
                    else
                        return false;
                }else return false;
            });
        }else return false;
    });
}
```

this function `isAvailableForUserRegister` will return if email/identity/phone already exist in collection :

```
Identity in Customer
Email in User_Customer
Phone in User_Customer
```

and the problem is process not continue enter to second subscribe, after i do breakpoint with my chrome, `cust` have `undefined` value.
please help me, how to solve this function?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a asynchronous problem, subscription is not ready, try this

```js
Meteor.subscribe("CUSTOMER").ready();
Meteor.subscribe("USER_CUSTOMER").ready();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Meteor.subscribe` only once inside the client.

*Client code:*

```
Meteor.subscribe("CUSTOMER");
Meteor.subscribe("USER_CUSTOMER");

function isAvailableForUserRegister(email,identiy,phone){
  var cust = Customer.findOne({Identity: identiy});
  if(cust === null) {
    return false;
  }
  var uc1 = User_Customer.findOne({$or: [
    {"Email": email}, 
    {"Phone": phone}
  ]);
  return uc1 !== null;                
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i try your solution, but it still undefined